# Problem deleting list item in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: list, powershell

I want to delete a specific list item from a list.

If I go in UI and try to delete it, it throws access denied error. Even if I try to delete using below powershell it says the same thing.

If I try to view the version history of the item, it doesn't show anything. If I try to see item permission, it throws some error.

How do I get rid of it?. I am Site Collection Administrator.

```
if(-not(
Get-PSSnapin | Where { $_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"})
) {
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;
}

$web = get-spweb http://xyz/
$list = $web.lists | where {$_.title -eq “Employee”}
#Write-host “List $($list.title) has $($list.items.count) entries”


$list.getitembyid(4256).Delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **RunWithElevatedPrivileges**....

```
    if(-not(Get-PSSnapin | Where { $_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"})) {
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;
}

[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
{
    $web = get-spweb http://xyz/
    $list = $web.lists | where {$_.title -eq “Employee”}
    #Write-host “List $($list.title) has $($list.items.count) entries”


    $list.getitembyid(4256).Delete()
})
```